# List datasets from geodatabase faster

Tags: python, arcpy

I'm using a script to list datasets from multiple gdbs in ArcPy (to rename most datasets and gdbs). Which looks like this:

```
dir_gdbs = 'D:\\mypath'
os.chdir(dir_gdbs)

lista_gdbs = glob.glob('*.gdb')
for i in lista_gdbs:
    gdb = (os.path.join(dir_gdbs,i))
    arcpy.env.workspace = gdb
    lista_capas = arcpy.ListDatasets()
    for u in lista_capas:
        #do stuff
```

It works correctly but there are many gdbs to process and it is very slow. Most of its time is lost changing the workspace (`arcpy.env.workspace = gdb`). Is there any way to list the datasets within each gdb without doing this?

Comment: I'd try `arcpy.da.Walk()` in place of `glob`.

Comment: @PolyGeo I did't know that function, I'll try it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally used `arcpy.da.walk()` as PolyGeo suggested.

```
walk = arcpy.da.Walk(dir_gdbs)
for gdb, x, capas in walk:
    for capa in capas:
        dir, gdb = os.path.split(gdb)
        #do stuff
```